# Elixir add timezone data to naive date time

Tags: datetime, elixir, phoenix-framework, datetime-conversion

I have a `NaiveDateTime` that I need to add timezone data to. For example if I have a `naive_date` value like `~N[2015-10-03 12:00:00.000000]` and I want set it to "America/Los_Angeles" timezone, how is that possible in Elixir?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using Timex Package, one could:

Update: better solution

```
iex> use timex

iex> naive_date = ~N[2015-10-03 12:00:00.000000]

iex> Timex.to_datetime(naive_date, "America/Los_Angeles")
#DateTime<2015-10-03 12:00:00-07:00 PDT America/Los_Angeles>
```

Old solution

```
use timex

utc_time = DateTime.from_naive!(~N[2015-10-03 12:00:00.000000], "Etc/UTC")

tz_offset =
  Timex.timezone("America/Los_Angeles", utc_time)
  |> Timex.Timezone.total_offset()

Timex.shift(utc_time, seconds: -tz_offset)
  |> Timezone.convert("America/Los_Angeles")
```

Comment: `Timex` is not an Elixir core in the first place and you should at least mention that for this to work the `timex` package should be included into the list of `deps`.

Answer (score 8):

According the the [**`NaiveDateTime`**](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/NaiveDateTime.html) documentation:

> We call them "naive" because this datetime representation does not have a time zone.

That means **you can't add timezone data to a `NaiveDateTime` object**.

---

However **you can convert a `NaiveDateTime` to a `DateTime`** that can hold time zone data with [**`DateTime.from_naive!/2`**](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/DateTime.html#from_naive!/2):

```rb
DateTime.from_naive!(~N[2015-10-03 12:00:00.000000], "Etc/UTC")
```

Comment: Per @larskris's response, where you link to in the docs, it does say "currently it only supports “Etc/UTC” as time zone".

Comment: I edited the response to make it more clear that a timezone database can be specified.